# Scala Custome Typed Class

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following lines of code in Scala.

```
abstract class Template[A,B] {
    def myMethod[A,B](): A=>B
}  
val concreate = new Template[Int,Int] { 
    def myMethod() = (x:Int) => x*x 
}
```

The Template class is a typed one and has an abstract method which returns a function of type Function1.
In the next step, I anonymously instantiate the Template class by supplying type parameters and I implement the abstract method as well.

But the compiler throws error in the second step. The error message is:

```
Object creation impossible, since method myMethod in class Template of type [A,B]() A=>B is not defined
```

I am not sure why the error occurs though I supply the type as well as the implementation. When I define the method, I understand that I don't need to supply the type since compiler can infer it from the anonymous class instantiation. Even I tried explicitly providing the type for method implementation. I am still getting the error.

Could someone please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, you're implementing `method` but you need to implement `myMethod`. That's why it's not defined.

Second, it wouldn't work anyway since you're shadowing the class type params with method type params. The definition of template is equivalent to the following:

```scala
abstract class Template[A,B] {
    def myMethod[C,D](): C => D // note how A and B don't matter at all.
}
```

You likely want to have parameters only on class:

```scala
abstract class Template[A,B] {
    def myMethod(): A => B
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg! It was a typo that I gave the name as method. Now I corrected it in my question. So if I understand correctly: If I want to use the same type parameters of the class in the methods, I should not parameterize the method again. Am I correct ?

Comment: You can reference both class type parameters and method type parameters in the same method. Just don't give them conflicting names: `def myMethod[C,D]: A => B => C => D = ???`

Comment: Method type parameters mean something different tho. You can fix A and B on a class level, but you can't fix C and D on method level at all. In that example by @jwvh, any implementor of `Template#myMethod` must support _all possible types_ for C and D. That's useful (e.g. `list.map(f)` works always, no matter what `f` returns), but scenario is different.